# how to add mysql db to my project?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I write a program with netbeans.

I connect my program to mysql an use from db that I made in mysql and it work correct.

Now I create .jar file from my project and it works but didn't connect to mysql and don't show any data but I am sure that I have information in my database.

What is problem?

Comment: A bit of code would have helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do more debugging.  Make sure you are catching and logging or printing out exceptions.  They should indicate a more specific problem.  Make sure you have all the needed drivers and depended libraries in the class path of the .jar you are trying to run.

Comment: @Mehdi, whatever ones you are using.  At the least you are using a mysql driver.

Comment: I add MySQL driver in my class path.

Answer (score 0):

May be you missed to pack MySql jar in your jar.

---

What error do you get? Its hard to say proper solution with the information you have provided.

Comment: i didn't add pack Mysql jar in my jar how can i add it? it didn't have any error just didn't show any data

Comment: I don't know if there is option in netBeans to including libs. But if you wanna do using ANT file then try this: http://blog.exploid.org/2008/03/howto-make-one-jar-file-with-netbeans.html Also read this: http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html